# jQuery browse in div

Tags: jquery

I'm currently creating a jquery based dynamic website. I have a top div and a bottom div.
In the middle I have a content div. I want to use # to navigate through my website with the content loaded in the content div. The navigation is in the bottom div.

You must can reach the pages with #.
Example: example.com/#settings needs to open settings.php in the content div. But also when i click the Settings link in the bottom div, the content div must contain settings.php

Can anyone help?

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use hashchange:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange

You'll get the current hash and be able to call an ajax function that will retrieve the correct page and inject the correct content.